# Python requests - HTTPDigest: Setting the hash algorithm to SHA-512 in Digest authorization

Tags: python, python-requests, digest-authentication

I'm trying to write a small Python function to connect to a site which uses the HTTP Digest authorization with the SHA-512 algorithm.
The code with which I'm trying to achieve this is:

```
headers = {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     'Encoding': 'utf-8',
}

s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)
s.auth = HTTPDigestAuth(self.username, self.passw)

r = requests.Request(
     url=self.api_url,
     method='POST',
     json=data
)

prepped = s.prepare_request(r)
r = s.send(prepped)
```

The problem is that I'm getting a 401 as a response. I was able to validate the username/password/address parameters and they are correct, and if I 'hack' the Authorization header to contain the SHA-512-encoded 
 values, then I'm getting an 502 error (which is kinda correct, as the rest of the message will not be correct)

If I read the code correctly, the basic hash algorithm used by HTTPDigestAuth is MD5. What I could not find was a way to change it the SHA-512, even though it's technically also supported. Could anyone please help me with this? It's driving me nuts.

Comment: I _think_ requests expects to get the algorithm from the `www-authenticate` header sent by the server, so the process is opaque from the client side.  But I'm not an expert ...

Comment: I've come to the same conclusion in the meantime. Apparently the server is not RFC2617-compliant (strange, as it's a normal ASP.NET web service), so requests cannot help me in this case.

As far as I can see, I have two options to get this to work:
 - use pyCurl to make everything work manually (lots of work, but should work)
 - calculate the hash by hand and use that while communicating with the server

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that although the documentation *said* that the server is using Digest authentication, they couldn't manage to implement that and the username and password fields just need to be passed in the POST data. The 502 error was caused by the auth server crashing when it tried to parse the Authorization header, because that handler was not implemented.

Case closed, in a way.