# How can I get python requests use MD5 for digests?

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to authenticate with a webserver using HTTP digest. The server announces that it supports digest with MD5 and SHA256 hashes. The Python requests lib automatically chooses sha256 in that case - which than doesn't work because the server has a known bug, that will not be fixed in ages - if ever.

How can I make python requests use MD5?

Comment: From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61027501/7867968) it looks like that may be set by the server, and not you

Comment: The server announces the supported hashes, and the client chooses from them. My server announces MD5 and SHA256, and Python requests chooses SHA256